Help with Ubuntu boot up
Screenshot from recovery mode:


I recently installed Ubuntu, and was seeing if i could dual boot Windows from Ubuntu. I think I messed around with one of the partitions (it let me unmount it, so i didn't think anything was wrong) then after a few minutes stuff started freezing up. I shut down my laptop, turned it back on and was met with a long boot, followed by this screen. I'm not sure what to do from here. I'm completely out of my depth. I use a MSI Raider laptop

Ok, I found recovery mode and the file system that is holding ubuntu. I don’t know where to mount it or how. (i tried sudo mount but it said the file system was already mounted on “/“)

You seem to have umounted the drive Ubuntu was on. Unlike Windows, Ubuntu lets you do dangerous things, it simmply asks you to become root. I guess recovery mode won't function either.
You should boot up from the installation media you have (usb stick or DVD) and select "Try Ubuntu". Then you have to find your Ubuntu partition. Type
df -h

This cannot do any harm, it simply lists your drives and partitions and gives you an additional hint by telling you the size of each and how much data is on it.
Identify the drive you have to mount.
The mount point for the active partition is usually the root (called /) of the system. But I've never had to do it from an installation disk so I'm not going to guess the precise command. Please read the documentation online.
Take notes (on some other medium), then if you make a mistake you will know what it was and you will be able to undo it. If you simply make a syntax error it won't so any harm, you will just see an error message. You will have to reboot after each attempt so it can take a while, but eventually you'll get your Ubuntu back along with all your data.

I was able to enter recovery mode. There wasn’t much I could do from there though. I’ll see what i can do

Give me a moment, i can send a screenshot at the part where i hit a roadblock

All listed disks are mounted. Your Ubuntu seems to be on nvme0n1p2. Hmm. Apart from trying to unmount the disk, do you remember what you did?

No, i don’t recall messing with anything else. I thought i dismounted nvme0n1p1 (though that was the root of my booting issue) but apparently not. I’m at a loss here. I only installed ubuntu recently, so I think i’m just gonna boot up ubuntu from the start again. Nothing important on my pc yet.
